# get the url values in multi dimensional array

Tags: php, drupal

i am having link like  below in drupal page and i want to have avalues in item array as multidimensional array
like,  items(1=>('productcode'=>'','mrp'=>'','listprice'=>''),2=>(('productcode'=>'','mrp'=>'','listprice'=>''));

[http://test.frontalrain.com/pricelist/edit/add?items[0][slno]=1&items[0][productcode]=Alexin&items[0][uom]=KGS&items[0][validfromdate][date]=06-04-2014&items[0][listprice]=111.00&items[0][mrp]=102.00&items[0][freight]=0.00&items[0][priceloc]=KA&items[0][states]=&items[0][city]=&items[0][storepks]=&items[0][productpk]=153&items[0][toaccountpk]=&items[0][dbaction]=&items[1][slno]=2&items[1][productcode]=Alexin&items[1][uom]=BAG20&items[1][validfromdate][date]=05-04-2014&items[1][listprice]=110.00&items[1][mrp]=101.00&items[1][freight]=0.00&items[1][priceloc]=AP&items[1][states]=&items[1][city]=&items[1][storepks]=&items[1][productpk]=153&items[1][toaccountpk]=&items[1][dbaction]=&items[2][slno]=3&items[2][productcode]=Alexin&items[2][uom]=KGS&items[2][validfromdate][date]=06-04-2014&items[2][listprice]=106.00&items[2][mrp]=102.00&items[2][freight]=0.00&items[2][priceloc]=AP&items[2][states]=&items[2][city]=&items[2][storepks]=&items[2][productpk]=153&items[2][toaccountpk]=&items[2][dbaction]=&items[3][slno]=4&items[3][productcode]=Alexin&items[3][uom]=KGS&items[3][validfromdate][date]=08-04-2014&items[3][listprice]=105.00&items[3][mrp]=200.00&items[3][freight]=0.00&items[3][priceloc]=AP&items[3][states]=&items[3][city]=&items[3][storepks]=&items[3][productpk]=153&items[3][toaccountpk]=&items[3][dbaction]=](http://test.frontalrain.com/pricelist/edit/add?items%5b0%5d%5bslno%5d=1&items%5b0%5d%5bproductcode%5d=Alexin&items%5b0%5d%5buom%5d=KGS&items%5b0%5d%5bvalidfromdate%5d%5bdate%5d=06-04-2014&items%5b0%5d%5blistprice%5d=111.00&items%5b0%5d%5bmrp%5d=102.00&items%5b0%5d%5bfreight%5d=0.00&items%5b0%5d%5bpriceloc%5d=KA&items%5b0%5d%5bstates%5d=&items%5b0%5d%5bcity%5d=&items%5b0%5d%5bstorepks%5d=&items%5b0%5d%5bproductpk%5d=153&items%5b0%5d%5btoaccountpk%5d=&items%5b0%5d%5bdbaction%5d=&items%5b1%5d%5bslno%5d=2&items%5b1%5d%5bproductcode%5d=Alexin&items%5b1%5d%5buom%5d=BAG20&items%5b1%5d%5bvalidfromdate%5d%5bdate%5d=05-04-2014&items%5b1%5d%5blistprice%5d=110.00&items%5b1%5d%5bmrp%5d=101.00&items%5b1%5d%5bfreight%5d=0.00&items%5b1%5d%5bpriceloc%5d=AP&items%5b1%5d%5bstates%5d=&items%5b1%5d%5bcity%5d=&items%5b1%5d%5bstorepks%5d=&items%5b1%5d%5bproductpk%5d=153&items%5b1%5d%5btoaccountpk%5d=&items%5b1%5d%5bdbaction%5d=&items%5b2%5d%5bslno%5d=3&items%5b2%5d%5bproductcode%5d=Alexin&items%5b2%5d%5buom%5d=KGS&items%5b2%5d%5bvalidfromdate%5d%5bdate%5d=06-04-2014&items%5b2%5d%5blistprice%5d=106.00&items%5b2%5d%5bmrp%5d=102.00&items%5b2%5d%5bfreight%5d=0.00&items%5b2%5d%5bpriceloc%5d=AP&items%5b2%5d%5bstates%5d=&items%5b2%5d%5bcity%5d=&items%5b2%5d%5bstorepks%5d=&items%5b2%5d%5bproductpk%5d=153&items%5b2%5d%5btoaccountpk%5d=&items%5b2%5d%5bdbaction%5d=&items%5b3%5d%5bslno%5d=4&items%5b3%5d%5bproductcode%5d=Alexin&items%5b3%5d%5buom%5d=KGS&items%5b3%5d%5bvalidfromdate%5d%5bdate%5d=08-04-2014&items%5b3%5d%5blistprice%5d=105.00&items%5b3%5d%5bmrp%5d=200.00&items%5b3%5d%5bfreight%5d=0.00&items%5b3%5d%5bpriceloc%5d=AP&items%5b3%5d%5bstates%5d=&items%5b3%5d%5bcity%5d=&items%5b3%5d%5bstorepks%5d=&items%5b3%5d%5bproductpk%5d=153&items%5b3%5d%5btoaccountpk%5d=&items%5b3%5d%5bdbaction%5d=)

Comment: Probably you're looking for `parse_str`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the functions [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
$URL = "http://test.frontalrain.com/pricelist/edit/add?items[0][slno]=1&items[0][productcode]=Alexin&items[0][uom]=KGS&items[0][validfromdate][date]=06-04-2014&items[0][listprice]=111.00&items[0][mrp]=102.00&items[0][freight]=0.00&items[0][priceloc]=KA&items[0][states]=&items[0][city]=&items[0][storepks]=&items[0][productpk]=153&items[0][toaccountpk]=&items[0][dbaction]=&items[1][slno]=2&items[1][productcode]=Alexin&items[1][uom]=BAG20&items[1][validfromdate][date]=05-04-2014&items[1][listprice]=110.00&items[1][mrp]=101.00&items[1][freight]=0.00&items[1][priceloc]=AP&items[1][states]=&items[1][city]=&items[1][storepks]=&items[1][productpk]=153&items[1][toaccountpk]=&items[1][dbaction]=&items[2][slno]=3&items[2][productcode]=Alexin&items[2][uom]=KGS&items[2][validfromdate][date]=06-04-2014&items[2][listprice]=106.00&items[2][mrp]=102.00&items[2][freight]=0.00&items[2][priceloc]=AP&items[2][states]=&items[2][city]=&items[2][storepks]=&items[2][productpk]=153&items[2][toaccountpk]=&items[2][dbaction]=&items[3][slno]=4&items[3][productcode]=Alexin&items[3][uom]=KGS&items[3][validfromdate][date]=08-04-2014&items[3][listprice]=105.00&items[3][mrp]=200.00&items[3][freight]=0.00&items[3][priceloc]=AP&items[3][states]=&items[3][city]=&items[3][storepks]=&items[3][productpk]=153&items[3][toaccountpk]=&items[3][dbaction]=";
$purl = parse_url($URL);
parse_str($purl["query"], $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/142346)

Answer (score 1):

You can use parse_str function as seen in the following code.

```
<?php

$qs = "items[0][slno]=1&items[0][productcode]=Alexin&items[0][uom]=KGS&items[0][validfromdate][date]=06-04-2014&items[0][listprice]=111.00&items[0][mrp]=102.00&items[0][freight]=0.00&items[0][priceloc]=KA&items[0][states]=&items[0][city]=&items[0][storepks]=&items[0][productpk]=153&items[0][toaccountpk]=&items[0][dbaction]=&items[1][slno]=2&items[1][productcode]=Alexin&items[1][uom]=BAG20&items[1][validfromdate][date]=05-04-2014&items[1][listprice]=110.00&items[1][mrp]=101.00&items[1][freight]=0.00&items[1][priceloc]=AP&items[1][states]=&items[1][city]=&items[1][storepks]=&items[1][productpk]=153&items[1][toaccountpk]=&items[1][dbaction]=&items[2][slno]=3&items[2][productcode]=Alexin&items[2][uom]=KGS&items[2][validfromdate][date]=06-04-2014&items[2][listprice]=106.00&items[2][mrp]=102.00&items[2][freight]=0.00&items[2][priceloc]=AP&items[2][states]=&items[2][city]=&items[2][storepks]=&items[2][productpk]=153&items[2][toaccountpk]=&items[2][dbaction]=&items[3][slno]=4&items[3][productcode]=Alexin&items[3][uom]=KGS&items[3][validfromdate][date]=08-04-2014&items[3][listprice]=105.00&items[3][mrp]=200.00&items[3][freight]=0.00&items[3][priceloc]=AP&items[3][states]=&items[3][city]=&items[3][storepks]=&items[3][productpk]=153&items[3][toaccountpk]=&items[3][dbaction]=";

parse_str( $qs, $out );
print_r( $out );

?>
```

HTH